# Looking for any key pressed down except for a specified key in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game where the player can do two things: move (spacebar) and show their score (any other key). I currently have this piece of code, which only checks for the A key, but I'd like it to activate when any key is pressed, except for the spacebar (including space would interfere with the movement)

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
    print("score visible")
```

In short: I want an if statement that is True when any key is pressed except for space.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like, (I don't remember the actual pygame syntax) pygame alternative to `if not pygame.key.pressed('space'): #do something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in your question:

> I want an if statement that is True when **any** key is pressed **except** for space.

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if any(key) and not key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    print("score visible")
```